# Swashbuckle.OData doesn't add controller if I change the Entity Set name

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, swashbuckle

I have Swashbuckle.OData working with OData (4.0) in an Web Api project.

It's all working fine, but when I change the 'Entity Set' name in the OData config, the OData controller no longer shows up in the swagger JSON file, and consequently the Swagger UI.

This works: builder.EntitySet("AccountRecords");
This does not work: builder.EntitySet("Records");

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing? How do I 'tell' Swashbuckle.OData that the name is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the controller and `EntitySet` should match. For your `AccountRecords` you should have a `AccountRecordsController` (which I guess you have) and if you rename the entity to `Records` the controller name should be `RecordsController`.
This is not a Swashbuckle/Swagger problem but WebAPI naming convention.

I wonder if your API actually works if the names don't match.